# Why isn't thic clock initialisation code work - STM32F205

Tags: stm32, clock, pll, stm32f2

```
#include <stm32f2xx_gpio.h>
#include <stm32f2xx_rcc.h>
#include <stm32f2xx_flash.h>
#include <stm32f2xx_exti.h> 
#include <stm32f2xx.h>
#include <stm32f2xx_syscfg.h>
#include <misc.h>

void SetupClock()
{
RCC->CR |= 1 << 16;

while ((RCC->CR & 1 << 17) == RESET) {}

//RCC->PLLCFGR |= 1 << 17;
RCC->PLLCFGR = 0x5401E06;

RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 4 | 1 << 5 | 1 << 6 | 1 << 7 | 1 << 11 | 1 << 14 | 1 << 13);
RCC->CFGR |= 1 << 10 | 1 << 12;
RCC->CFGR |= 1 << 15;

FLASH->ACR &= ~(1 << 2);
FLASH->ACR |= 1 << 0 | 1 << 1;

RCC->CR |= 1 << 24;

while ((RCC->CR & 1 << 25) == RESET) {}

RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 0);
RCC->CFGR |= 1 << 1;

while (((RCC->CFGR & 1 << 2) != RESET) && ((RCC->CFGR & 1 << 3) != SET)) { }
}

int main()
{
SetupClock();

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

for (;;)
{
  GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_6, Bit_SET);
  asm("nop");
  < ... >
  asm("nop");
  GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_6, Bit_RESET);
  asm("nop");
  < ... >
  asm("nop");
}
}
```

The code is written according to manual but the frequency is off.

Comment: What doesn't work? How can you tell? What is happening? What should happen?

Comment: Too many magic numbers. There should be `#define`s for all those Bits in a verdor supplied header file.

Comment: "the frequency is off" - what does that mean? Do you have your code running? Have you stepped it over with debugger? Does it jump to a Hard Failure ISR?

Comment: I don't have a debugger. I changed the amount of NOPs between toggles and calculated the frequency from the data from a logical analyser. The frequency was about 32MHZ, just like without any clock code.

Comment: Where are the code comments? How is this electronics design? Have you asked on the STM forums?

Comment: Also, why mess with register-level programming when you have an extensive library to deal with it without any black magic? (`RCC_*` functions).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a device, and it's particular set up code, not electronics design.

Comment: @KyranF  This question is more *unclear* than *off-topic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
void SetupClock()
{
RCC->CR |= 1 << 16;

while ((RCC->CR & 1 << 17) == RESET) {}

//RCC->PLLCFGR |= 1 << 17;
RCC->PLLCFGR = 0x5401E06;

RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 4 | 1 << 5 | 1 << 6 | 1 << 7 | 1 << 11 | 1 << 14 | 1 << 13);
RCC->CFGR |= 1 << 10 | 1 << 12;
RCC->CFGR |= 1 << 15;

FLASH->ACR &= ~(1 << 2);
FLASH->ACR |= 1 << 0 | 1 << 1 | 1 << 8 | 1 << 9 | 1 << 10;

RCC->CR |= 1 << 24;

while ((RCC->CR & 1 << 25) == RESET) {}

RCC->CFGR &= ~(1 << 0);
RCC->CFGR |= 1 << 1;

while (((RCC->CFGR & 1 << 2) != RESET) && ((RCC->CFGR & 1 << 3) != SET)) { }
}
```

With

```
SetSysClock();
```

Commented out in init file.

Comment: So, you've found the answer? And it was just that? So it was a software/setup issue... not sure if this entire question is relevant enough to stay on this site..

Comment: If you ever intend to use the global variable SystemCoreClock such as in a call to set up the SysTick_Handler() using something like SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000); you will either need to set this variable yourself or call SystemCoreClockUpdate(); which is probably in your init file (system_stm32f2xx.c ?) since you are setting up the clock yourself. The comments for SystemCoreClockUpdate() read "Updates the variable SystemCoreClock and must be called whenever the core clock is changed during program execution.".

Comment: Why aren't you letting system_stm32f2xx.c do the clock setup via the function SetSysClock()? You can edit that if you need to. There should be no need for your SetupClock() function.